# Show some formatted text in WPF which the user can copy to word

Tags: wpf, formatting, richtext

I want to show some formatted text in a client WPF application which the user can select and copy to word.

It needs to be easily created by the app, and the biggest formatting thing inside is a table where some cells are right-aligned.

What is best to use here? A richtext control is hard to fill (I think) and html is not easy to show, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure RichTextBox should be your answer.

You would have a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779.aspx) containing a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) containing your [Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133.aspx).

From that first article:

> The RichTextBox control enables you to
>   display or edit flow content including
>   paragraphs, images, tables, and more.
>   This topic introduces the TextBox
>   class and provides examples of how to
>   use it in both Extensible Application
>   Markup Language (XAML) and C#.

```
<RichTextBox>
  <FlowDocument>
    <Table>
      <TableRowGroup>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>
            <!-- One or more Block-derived object… -->
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableRowGroup>
    </Table>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

When content is copied from a RichTextBox, it's treated as standard RTF, so Word will recognize most (if not all) of the formatting.

Interesting thought: FlowDocuments are closely related to the XPS file format, which Windows 7/Vista can print natively to. There's a huge amount of interoperability between Silverlight/WPF/XPS and to some extent even Word 2007 docx files.

I even faintly remember editing an XPS file in Visual Studio's WPF designer -- though don't quote me on that, since it was quite a few years ago and I don't remember what exactly I did.